# JPA + Hibernate + java.util.logging (JDK logging): show sql queries with arguments

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, logging

We are using JPA with Hibernate, and because we use the java build-in logging for our project, we have routed Hibernate to use java.util.logging (JDK logging) as well (by including slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar). Now there is a problem with showing the actual queries that hibernate/JPA performs. We have added this to our persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```

That helps a bit, showing some more queries when inserting stuff. However, the question marks still remain. Other answers suggest to set the org.hibernate.type to TRACE in order to solve this, but that is a log4j specific suggestion. How can we actually show all arguments that hibernate uses? Thanks!

Comment: you can't without a logging system (like log4j)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use JDBC Driver Proxy logging library like [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)

log4jdbc uses the Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) and supports below logging systems:-

```
Log4j
java.util logging in JDK 1.4
logback
Jakarta Commons Logging
```

It support showing SQL Queries with parameters ..here is an excerpt from their documentation

> jdbc.sqlonly :- Logs only SQL. SQL executed within a prepared statement
>   is automatically shown with it's bind arguments replaced with the data
>   bound at that position, for greatly increased readability

Answer (score 0):

create a logging.properties, add the line org.hibernate.SQL.level=FINEST, and launch your program with -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties VM argument